# Drupal CMS - Find Content - how to drop the ?destination=admin/content in the edit link?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using drupal 7.  When I go to the CMS at the url `http://mysite.com/admin/content`, the edit link for each of the content records are

`http://mysite.com/node/206/edit?destination=admin/content`

I want to convert the url to:

`http://mysite.com/node/206/edit`

How do I do this?

The reason I want to do this is because I want the user to always see the result of his work after he's saved it. Additionally, there are important Call-To-Action requirements on the `/node/206/edit` page that appear immediately after saving a record.  These CTA requirements are not available in the admin/content area.

**Additional Info**
I applied a bandaid solution for now.  I went into my admin theme at `/theme/nameoftheme/page.tpl.php`, then I replaced the statement

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

with

```
<?php print str_replace('/edit?destination=admin/content', '/edit', render($page['content'])); ?>
```

Can someone please provide me with a more elegant solution, so I don't have to use this band-aid solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the content editing screens returning the user to that. If they edit content from the front-end, the destination is the node.

You can override that default content manager with a View configured the way you want it. The 'Edit' link won't have a destination in the URL, and if I recall, it will return the user to the content after editing.

Also, if this is D6 and they have access to this page it sounds like they have administer nodes access. You might want to tune the permissions differently and setup a view so you can override admin/content path(s) with your View to override the content manager.